# Python convert bs4.element.Tag (html table) into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

We are looking to scrape a table from the following website:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
import pandas as pd

base_url = "https://www.riaa.com/gold-platinum/#"
headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36' }
response = requests.get(base_url, headers=headers)
web_page = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page, "html.parser")
main_table = soup.find("table")
```

`type(main_table)` is `bs4.element.Tag`, and we are struggling to convert this into a pandas dataframe. We can do the pandas cleaning to get the table exactly how we need it, but we are not sure how to get this into pandas in the first place. Is this possible? Are we grabbing the table in the right way to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that only using pandas and requests as follows:

Code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36'}

url = "https://www.riaa.com/gold-platinum/#"

req = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

wiki_table = pd.read_html(req.text, attrs = {"class":"table-responsive"} )

df = wiki_table[0]#.to_csv('score.csv',index = False)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
Award  ...                                         Unnamed: 6
0   SHARE  ...  CODY JOHNSON  Title: AIN'T NOTHIN' TO IT  Cert...
1   SHARE  ...  CARRIE UNDERWOOD  Title: BEFORE HE CHEATS  Cer...
2   SHARE  ...  CARRIE UNDERWOOD  Title: SOME HEARTS  Certific...
3   SHARE  ...  CORDAE  Title: BROKE AS FUCK  Certification Da...
4   SHARE  ...  RL GRIME  Title: UCLA (FEAT. 24HRS)  Certifica...
5   SHARE  ...  VICTOR MANUELLE & LA INDIA  Title: VÍCTIMAS LA...
6   SHARE  ...  YOUNGBOY NEVER BROKE AGAIN  Title: DRUG ADDICT...
7   SHARE  ...  YOUNGBOY NEVER BROKE AGAIN  Title: ALL IN  Cer...
8   SHARE  ...  YOUNGBOY NEVER BROKE AGAIN  Title: MY WINDOW  ...
9   SHARE  ...  YOUNGBOY NEVER BROKE AGAIN  Title: HOUSE ARRES...
10  SHARE  ...  A$AP FERG  Title: WORK REMIX (FEAT. A$AP ROCKY...
11  SHARE  ...  A$AP FERG  Title: SHABBA (FEAT. A$AP ROCKY)  C...
12  SHARE  ...  A$AP FERG  Title: NEW LEVEL (FEAT. FUTURE)  Ce...
13  SHARE  ...  A$AP FERG  Title: PLAIN JANE  Certification Da...
14  SHARE  ...  COBRA STARSHIP  Title: HOT MESS  Certification...
15  SHARE  ...  DMX  Title: SLIPPIN'  Certification Date: Octo...
16  SHARE  ...  ELLA MAI  Title: ELLA MAI  Certification Date:...
17  SHARE  ...  HARRY STYLES  Title: WATERMELON SUGAR  Certifi...
18  SHARE  ...  HERENCIA DE PATRONES  Title: COSAS DE LA CLICA...
19  SHARE  ...  HERENCIA DE PATRONES  Title: PA LAS VIBRAS  Ce...
20  SHARE  ...  JIMMY HUMILDE  Title: JIMMY HUMILDE PRESENTA L...
21  SHARE  ...  JOWELL & RANDY  Title: LOS MAS SUELTOS DEL REG...
22  SHARE  ...  MY CHEMICAL ROMANCE  Title: WELCOME TO THE BLA...
23  SHARE  ...  MY CHEMICAL ROMANCE  Title: MAMA  Certificatio...
24  SHARE  ...  MY CHEMICAL ROMANCE  Title: I DON'T LOVE YOU  ...
25  SHARE  ...  MY CHEMICAL ROMANCE  Title: DEAD!  Certificati...
26  SHARE  ...  MY CHEMICAL ROMANCE  Title: CANCER  Certificat...
27  SHARE  ...  MY CHEMICAL ROMANCE  Title: FAMOUS LAST WORDS ...
28  SHARE  ...  MY CHEMICAL ROMANCE  Title: TEENAGERS  Certifi...
29  SHARE  ...  NATANAEL CANO  Title: CORRIDOS TUMABDOS  Certi...

[30 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Seems like a lot of python web scraping can be done **without** beautifulsoup...

Comment: this is helpful however this only returns the table text. it would be helpful for me to access some of the other elements in the table (e.g. the href in the image in the first column, rather than the word SHARE).

Comment: @Canovice  yes , your thinking is right . pandas can return  table tex  meaning  Pandas can grab only  table data from html dom  and can't grab link. Thanks